# Error al convertir tipo de datos en SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Estoy extrayendo información hasta un día anterior que el actual con la siguiente consulta:

```
select VL.NROACT,  VL.NROVOL, VL.CODTYPVOL, VL.ARRIVEEM, VL.DEPARTM, VL.APD, VL.APDPREV, VL.DATDEPP, VL.HRDEP, 
VL.SDDP, VL.STD, VL.EDDP, VL.ETD, VL.ADDP, VL.ATD, VL.ADDCRP, VL.ATDCR, VL.DDEPABOPP, VL.HRDEPABOP, VL.DATDEPABP, 
VL.HRDEPAB, VL.APA, VL.APAPREV, VL.DATARRP, VL.HRARR, VL.SDAP,  VL.STA, VL.EDAP, VL.ETA, VL.ADAP, VL.ATA, 
VL.ADACRP, VL.ATACR, VL.DARRABOPP, VL.HRARRABOP, VL.DATARRABP, VL.HRARRAB, VL.CODSER, VL.DATROTP, VL.SEQVROT, 
AV.CODAVION,AV.PAXMAX, 
VL31.PAXGGEMB, VL31.PAXEMB1, 
AO.CODAPO as CODAPO_O, AO.CODPAYSAP as CODPAYSAP_O, 
AD.CODAPO as CODAPO_D, AD.CODPAYSAP as CODPAYSAP_D, 
CDVL.CDEUNTSRV, 
VR.DESVERS 
from KEOPSDTA.VOLS as VL 
left join KEOPSDTA.AVION as AV on VL.CODAVION = AV.CODAVION 
left join (select NROACT, sum(PAXGGEMB) PAXGGEMB, sum(PAXEMB1) PAXEMB1  from KEOPSDTA.VOLS31 group by NROACT) as VL31 on VL.NROACT = VL31.NROACT 
left join KEOPSDTA.AEROP as AO on VL.APD = AO.CODAPI 
left join KEOPSDTA.AEROP as AD on VL.APA = AD.CODAPI 
left join KEOPSDTA.CDEDSVL as CDVL on AO.CODAPO = CDVL.CDEAPO and AD.CODAPO = CDVL.CDEAPD 
left join KEOPSDTA.VERSIONS as VR on SUBSTR(VL.CODAVION,1,4) = VR.CODVERS 
where SDDP between '20200501' and '20200519'
```

Pero si modifico la query y quiero obtener datos del día de hoy, es decir:

```
select VL.NROACT,  VL.NROVOL, VL.CODTYPVOL, VL.ARRIVEEM, VL.DEPARTM, VL.APD, VL.APDPREV, VL.DATDEPP, VL.HRDEP, 
VL.SDDP, VL.STD, VL.EDDP, VL.ETD, VL.ADDP, VL.ATD, VL.ADDCRP, VL.ATDCR, VL.DDEPABOPP, VL.HRDEPABOP, VL.DATDEPABP, 
VL.HRDEPAB, VL.APA, VL.APAPREV, VL.DATARRP, VL.HRARR, VL.SDAP,  VL.STA, VL.EDAP, VL.ETA, VL.ADAP, VL.ATA, 
VL.ADACRP, VL.ATACR, VL.DARRABOPP, VL.HRARRABOP, VL.DATARRABP, VL.HRARRAB, VL.CODSER, VL.DATROTP, VL.SEQVROT, 
AV.CODAVION,AV.PAXMAX, 
VL31.PAXGGEMB, VL31.PAXEMB1, 
AO.CODAPO as CODAPO_O, AO.CODPAYSAP as CODPAYSAP_O, 
AD.CODAPO as CODAPO_D, AD.CODPAYSAP as CODPAYSAP_D, 
CDVL.CDEUNTSRV, 
VR.DESVERS 
from KEOPSDTA.VOLS as VL 
left join KEOPSDTA.AVION as AV on VL.CODAVION = AV.CODAVION 
left join (select NROACT, sum(PAXGGEMB) PAXGGEMB, sum(PAXEMB1) PAXEMB1  from KEOPSDTA.VOLS31 group by NROACT) as VL31 on VL.NROACT = VL31.NROACT 
left join KEOPSDTA.AEROP as AO on VL.APD = AO.CODAPI 
left join KEOPSDTA.AEROP as AD on VL.APA = AD.CODAPI 
left join KEOPSDTA.CDEDSVL as CDVL on AO.CODAPO = CDVL.CDEAPO and AD.CODAPO = CDVL.CDEAPD 
left join KEOPSDTA.VERSIONS as VR on SUBSTR(VL.CODAVION,1,4) = VR.CODVERS 
where SDDP between '20200501' and '20200520'
```

Me manda los siguientes errores:

***[Transformaciones [288]] Error: An error occurred while attempting to perform a type cast.
[Transformaciones [288]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.

The "Transformaciones" failed because error code 0xC0049064 occurred, and the error row disposition on 
"Transformaciones.Outputs[Derived Column Output].Columns[MINS_VUELO]" specifies failure on error. 
An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.

There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
[SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.

The ProcessInput method on component "Transformaciones" (288) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input 
"Derived Column Input" (289). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. 
The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.

There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.***

La columna derivada donde me marca el error es el siguiente:

***(DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING(ATDCR,1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING(ATDCR,3,2)) < (DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING(HRARRAB,1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING(HRARRAB,3,2)) ? DATEDIFF("mi",(DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING(ATDCR,1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING(ATDCR,3,2)),(DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING(HRARRAB,1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING(HRARRAB,3,2))) : DATEDIFF("mi",(DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING(ATDCR,1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING(ATDCR,3,2)),DATEADD("Day",1,(DT_DBTIME)(SUBSTRING(HRARRAB,1,2) + ":" + SUBSTRING(HRARRAB,3,2))))***

Y las columnas a las que hace referencia son las siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quisiera saber porque solo puedo extraer información de días anteriores y no del día actual

Comment: Al día de hoy tendrás todos los datos? no es posible algún null, blanco o no calculado que impida la transformación

Comment: Antes que nada gracias por tu respuesta pero no es eso. Si mañana cargo los registros a día 20 los cargara, pero si hoy que es 20 los quiero cargar se vuelve imposible.

Comment: De nada Guillermo, de pronto MINS_VUELO tiene un valor esperado en la fecha actual?